# cups-bowsed: name of printer

Tags: printing

I'm using cups-browsed for auto-detect network printers installed on a server. Since updated from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 the name of printers has changed:

- in 16.04: 003-swlaser (queue name on server)
- in 18.04: lexmark_name
  of server (lexmark is the description on the server).

How do I get the old names based on the queue-name?